# How to set ctrl+v values from both web and workbook to not override format

Tags: excel, vba

Im using the following VBA module to maintain format of my cell when pasting. The macro is assigned to "CTRL+V" key.

```
Public Sub CopyPaste()
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

It works good when copying values from the same workbook. But when copying from web it gives me error "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed"

How can i improve my VBA code to maintain format even when pasting from web browser?

Alex

Comment: see here: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/09/17/vba-excelallow-paste-special-only/

Comment: Hi, it works great however it prevents me now from writing a value into a cell. I can paste the value but not write anything.